# Adding custom filter tag gtag.js

Tags: google-analytics

I've recently launched a new website for a customer, which will for a time run in parallel to their existing site, on the same domain.

I'm trying to find a simple way to setup a Google Analytics filter, to be able to distinguish traffic to the new site.

The catch is that the pages that make up the new site, do not share a common path prefix, so I can't just filter that way.

It's easy for me to add any changes that are required to the gtag snippet for the new site.

I thought perhaps I could do something like this...

```
gtag('config', 'UA-#######-#', { 'site_version': 'v2.0'});
```

Then I figured I might be able to create a filter in the Analytics admin, to do something like "tag:site_version=v2.0".

After more research I've realised that these extra options are called "Control parameters", and I apparently can't just make them up, as there is a pre-defined list of valid parameters, none of which seem in any way relevant for what I'm needing to do.

Is there a correct way to do what I'm trying to do? It seems like it should be a trivial requirement, but I'm having trouble finding the solution.

So in short, I want to be able to add some custom 'tag' to the gtag snippet, in order to be able to filter on this 'tag' in the Analytics console.

Answer (score 1):

## Changing the path in Google analytics

You can use [virtual pageviews](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/single-page-applications?hl=en) to track the two versions of the site. For example:

```
gtag('config', 'GA_TRACKING_ID', {'page_path': '/version1/url.html'});
```

You could also use `document.URL` to get the URL

```
gtag('config', 'GA_TRACKING_ID', {'page_path': '/version1/'+document.URL});
```

This solution changes the actual **dimension path** of the site so make sure you always keep a raw data view in Google Analytics.

## Adding a new dimension to Google analytics

Another solution is using [custom dimensions](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/custom-dims-mets?hl=en). Instead of changing the default path dimension, we create a new one (web_version).

```
gtag('config', 'GA_TRACKING_ID', {
  'web_version': {'dimension1': 'version1'}
});
```